# TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'list'> to Tensor. Contents: [None, 16, 16384, 128]. Consider casting elements to a supported type

Tags: python, tensorflow, input, dataformat, tensorflow-probability

I get the following error when fitting the model:
`TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'list'> to Tensor. Contents: [None, 16, 16384, 128]. Consider casting elements to a supported type.`

This is where I define the input shape in the model:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input

def model(input_shape=(4, 128, 128, 128),n_base_filters=16, depth=5, dropout_rate=0.3,
                      n_segmentation_levels=3, n_labels=4, optimizer=Adam, initial_learning_rate=5e-4,
                      loss_function=bin_crossentropy, activation_name="sigmoid",metrics=dice_coefficient):

    inputs = Input(input_shape)
    ......
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py in make_tensor_proto(values, dtype, shape, verify_shape, allow_broadcast)
    548     try:
--> 549       str_values = [compat.as_bytes(x) for x in proto_values]
    550     except TypeError:

24 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    548     try:
--> 549       str_values = [compat.as_bytes(x) for x in proto_values]
    550     except TypeError:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/compat.py in as_bytes(bytes_or_text, encoding)
     86     raise TypeError('Expected binary or unicode string, got %r' %
---> 87                     (bytes_or_text,))
     88 

TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-c79d6965b744> in <module>()
      1 model=model(input_shape=(4, 128, 128, 128),n_base_filters=16, depth=5, dropout_rate=0.3,
      2                       n_segmentation_levels=3, n_labels=4, optimizer=Adam, initial_learning_rate=5e-4,
----> 3                       loss_function=weighted_dice_coefficient_loss, activation_name="sigmoid",metrics=dice_coefficient)
      4 
      5 print(len(model.layers))

<ipython-input-55-051eee07240c> in model(input_shape, n_base_filters, depth, dropout_rate, n_segmentation_levels, n_labels, optimizer, initial_learning_rate, loss_function, activation_name, metrics)
     48 
     49         if current_layer is inputs:
---> 50             in_conv = create_convolution_block_flip(current_layer, n_level_filters)
     51         else:
     52             in_conv = create_convolution_block_flip(current_layer,n_level_filters, strides=(2, 2, 2))

<ipython-input-42-e2034c0ac3eb> in create_convolution_block_flip(input_layer, n_filters, num_train_examples, batch_normalization, kernel, activation, padding, strides, instance_normalization)
      7                             tf.cast(num_train_examples, dtype=tf.float32)) 
      8 
----> 9     layer = tfp.layers.Convolution3DFlipout(n_filters, kernel, padding=padding, strides=strides, data_format="channels_first",kernel_divergence_fn=kl_diverge_func)(input_layer)
     10 
     11 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    968     if _in_functional_construction_mode(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_list):
    969       return self._functional_construction_call(inputs, args, kwargs,
--> 970                                                 input_list)
    971 
    972     # Maintains info about the `Layer.call` stack.

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in _functional_construction_call(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_list)
   1106       # Check input assumptions set after layer building, e.g. input shape.
   1107       outputs = self._keras_tensor_symbolic_call(
-> 1108           inputs, input_masks, args, kwargs)
   1109 
   1110       if outputs is None:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in _keras_tensor_symbolic_call(self, inputs, input_masks, args, kwargs)
    838       return nest.map_structure(keras_tensor.KerasTensor, output_signature)
    839     else:
--> 840       return self._infer_output_signature(inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks)
    841 
    842   def _infer_output_signature(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in _infer_output_signature(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks)
    878           self._maybe_build(inputs)
    879           inputs = self._maybe_cast_inputs(inputs)
--> 880           outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    881 
    882         self._handle_activity_regularization(inputs, outputs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    690       try:
    691         with conversion_ctx:
--> 692           return converted_call(f, args, kwargs, options=options)
    693       except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    694         if hasattr(e, 'ag_error_metadata'):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in converted_call(f, args, kwargs, caller_fn_scope, options)
    334   if conversion.is_in_allowlist_cache(f, options):
    335     logging.log(2, 'Allowlisted %s: from cache', f)
--> 336     return _call_unconverted(f, args, kwargs, options, False)
    337 
    338   if ag_ctx.control_status_ctx().status == ag_ctx.Status.DISABLED:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in _call_unconverted(f, args, kwargs, options, update_cache)
    461 
    462   if kwargs is not None:
--> 463     return f(*args, **kwargs)
    464   return f(*args)
    465 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/layers/conv_variational.py in call(self, inputs)
    230 
    231     outputs = self._apply_variational_kernel(inputs)
--> 232     outputs = self._apply_variational_bias(outputs)
    233     if self.activation is not None:
    234       outputs = self.activation(outputs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/layers/conv_variational.py in _apply_variational_bias(self, inputs)
    386                                 [outputs_shape[0], outputs_shape[1],
    387                                  outputs_shape[2] * outputs_shape[3],
--> 388                                  outputs_shape[4]])
    389         outputs_4d = tf.nn.bias_add(outputs_4d,
    390                                     self.bias_posterior_tensor,

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    204     """Call target, and fall back on dispatchers if there is a TypeError."""
    205     try:
--> 206       return target(*args, **kwargs)
    207     except (TypeError, ValueError):
    208       # Note: convert_to_eager_tensor currently raises a ValueError, not a

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py in reshape(tensor, shape, name)
    193     A `Tensor`. Has the same type as `tensor`.
    194   """
--> 195   result = gen_array_ops.reshape(tensor, shape, name)
    196   tensor_util.maybe_set_static_shape(result, shape)
    197   return result

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py in reshape(tensor, shape, name)
   8396   # Add nodes to the TensorFlow graph.
   8397   _, _, _op, _outputs = _op_def_library._apply_op_helper(
-> 8398         "Reshape", tensor=tensor, shape=shape, name=name)
   8399   _result = _outputs[:]
   8400   if _execute.must_record_gradient():

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py in _apply_op_helper(op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    523         except TypeError as err:
    524           if dtype is None:
--> 525             raise err
    526           else:
    527             raise TypeError(

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py in _apply_op_helper(op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    513                   name=input_arg.name,
    514                   as_ref=input_arg.is_ref,
--> 515                   preferred_dtype=default_dtype)
    516           else:
    517             values = ops.convert_to_tensor(

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/profiler/trace.py in wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    161         with Trace(trace_name, **trace_kwargs):
    162           return func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 163       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    164 
    165     return wrapped

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype, dtype_hint, ctx, accepted_result_types)
   1564 
   1565     if ret is None:
-> 1566       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
   1567 
   1568     if ret is NotImplemented:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in _constant_tensor_conversion_function(v, dtype, name, as_ref)
    337                                          as_ref=False):
    338   _ = as_ref
--> 339   return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
    340 
    341 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in constant(value, dtype, shape, name)
    263   """
    264   return _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape=False,
--> 265                         allow_broadcast=True)
    266 
    267 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape, allow_broadcast)
    281       tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(
    282           value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape,
--> 283           allow_broadcast=allow_broadcast))
    284   dtype_value = attr_value_pb2.AttrValue(type=tensor_value.tensor.dtype)
    285   attrs = {"value": tensor_value, "dtype": dtype_value}

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py in make_tensor_proto(values, dtype, shape, verify_shape, allow_broadcast)
    551       raise TypeError("Failed to convert object of type %s to Tensor. "
    552                       "Contents: %s. Consider casting elements to a "
--> 553                       "supported type." % (type(values), values))
    554     tensor_proto.string_val.extend(str_values)
    555     return tensor_proto

TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'list'> to Tensor. Contents: [None, 16, 16384, 128]. Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

I know the error is arising from `layer = tfp.layers.Convolution3DFlipout(n_filters, kernel, padding=padding, strides=strides,data_format='channels_first')(input_layer)`. Default data_format in Convolution3DFlipout is `'channels_last'`. When I change it to `data_format='channels_first'`, it started to throw this.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you post the traceback?..it would be more helpful to understand.

Comment: Edited the question with Traceback.

Comment: The error is in the `model def` and happening in the part `create_convolution_block_flip(current_layer, n_level_filters)`. Maybe there is some list being returned.

Comment: I only have `layer = tfp.layers.Convolution3DFlipout(n_filters, kernel, padding=padding, strides=strides,data_format='channels_first')(input_layer)` in `create_convolution_block_flip( )`. Default data_format in `Convolution3DFlipout` is `'channels_last'`. When I change it to `data_format='channels_first`, it started to throw this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the following line from the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/blob/9e50fa39f37216dd084c24aa3dd14ab0d4dee926/tensorflow_probability/python/layers/conv_variational.py#L384):

```
outputs_shape = outputs.shape.as_list()
outputs_4d = tf.reshape(outputs,
                       [outputs_shape[0], outputs_shape[1],
                       outputs_shape[2] * outputs_shape[3],
                       outputs_shape[4]])
```

So your Convolution has 16 filters, and according to the reshaping `128*128 = 16384` which explains the shape in the error above.

The workaround is, you can edit line:

```
outputs_shape = outputs.shape.as_list()
```

To:

```
outputs_shape = tf.shape(outputs)
```

Here `outputs.shape` was static, with `tf.shape` it is dynamic now. I've run some unit tests with the following change, everything seemed fine so far.

Reproducible example, **before changing**:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp

print(tf.__version__) # 2.5.0
print(tfp.__version__) # 0.13.0

inputs = (3,32,32,32)

model2 = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Input(shape = inputs),
    tfp.layers.Convolution3DFlipout(
        64, kernel_size=5, padding='SAME', activation=tf.nn.relu,
        data_format = 'channels_first'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2),
                                 strides=(2, 2, 2),
                                 padding='SAME'),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tfp.layers.DenseFlipout(10),
])

TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'list'> to Tensor. Contents: [None, 64, 1024, 32]. Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

**After changing** to following line above in the source code `model.summary()` shows:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv3d_flipout (Conv3DFlipou (None, 64, 32, 32, 32)    48064     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling3d (MaxPooling3D) (None, 32, 16, 16, 32)    0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 262144)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_flipout (DenseFlipout) (None, 10)                5242890   
=================================================================
Total params: 5,290,954
Trainable params: 5,290,954
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to change the source code? Also, in the source code it says "# As of Mar 2017, direct addition is significantly slower than
        # bias_add when computing gradients. To use bias_add, we collapse Z
        # and Y into a single dimension to obtain a 4D input tensor." What does this actually mean?

Comment: The passed input is 5D including the batch size, so it is collapsed into 4D tensor. Notice your passed input was (None, 16, 16384, 128) where 16384 is product of 128*128 as I mentioned in my answer. Regarding to source code changing which IDE do you work at? Or you are working on Colab?

Comment: CTRL + Left Click the `Convolution3DFlipout`, it should take you to `conv_variational.py`. Then go to line 384 and change it as I suggested. Then restart the runtime.

Comment: Can you also please tell me, if it is in Jupyter Notebook or a remote server how I can do it?

Comment: You need dig into `venv` I think. You need to find where tensorflow-probability has installed. If you can find then `conv_variational.py` is in `tfp --> layers --> conv_variational.py`. Or you can try to download the notebook as .py and run it by using an IDE. Then when it throws an error you can go to `conv_variational.py` by clicking the related error. It should be connected via some hyperlink I think.

Comment: Thanks a lot. One last question, when my input_shape is (4,128,128,128), if I give input_shape in the neural network as (128,128,128,4) and leave the data_format='channels_last' (default), is it wrong?

Comment: Computations will differ. They are not the same thing. `channels_first` will compute according to `NCHW` and `channels_last` will do it as `NHWC`.

Comment: I've run the unit tests with the following change, seems fine.

Comment: I posted another question on TensorFlow probability: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68842244/tensorflow-probability-saving-and-loading-model. Can you please have a look at it?