# Tensorflow Probability: saving and loading model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-probability

I am trying to fit a model with TensorFlow probability, for example:

```
input = Input(shape=(32,32,32,3))
x = tfp.layers.Convolution3DReparameterization(
        64, kernel_size=5, padding='SAME', activation=tf.nn.relu,
        data_format = 'channels_first')(input)
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2),
                                 strides=(2, 2, 2),
                                 padding='SAME')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
output = tfp.layers.DenseFlipout(10)(x)

model3 = Model(input, output)
model3.save('tf_test_model3.h5')
```

When I load the model as `model3 = load_model('tf_test_model3.h5')`, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Unknown layer: Conv3DReparameterization. Please ensure this object is passed to the `custom_objects` argument.
```

When I pass it to custom_objects as:

```
custom_objects= {'Conv3DReparameterization': tfp.layers.Convolution3DReparameterization}
model3 = load_model('tf_test_model3.h5', custom_objects=custom_objects)
```

I get the following error:
`TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: What the versions of TensorFlow and TFP?

Comment: @Frightera Tensorflow version is 2.6.0 and TFP version is 0.13.0

Comment: I'd go with saving weights only and reload them after re-creating the model. For other error, I will have a look when I have time.

Comment: I tried that, but then I get another error when getting the shape of the output layer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68843958/how-to-get-shape-of-layers

Answer (score 0):

The bug in your code is   `data_format = channels_first`

You are giving input shape of (32,32,32,3) which is channel_last type data. providing edited code

```
import keras as tk
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(32,32,32,3))
x = tfp.layers.Convolution3DReparameterization(
        64, kernel_size=5, padding='SAME', activation=tf.nn.relu,
        data_format = 'channels_last')(input) #changed  from channels_first
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2),
                                 strides=(2, 2, 2),
                                 padding='SAME')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
output = tfp.layers.DenseFlipout(10)(x)

model3 = tk.Model(input, output)
model3.save('tf_test_model3.h5')
```