# How to get the shape of a probabilistic layer?

Tags: tensorflow, shapes, tf.keras, tensorflow-probability

I am a building model with TensorFlow probability layers. When I do, `model.output.shape`, I get an error:

`AttributeError: 'UserRegisteredSpec' object has no attribute '_shape'`

If I do, `output_shape = tf.shape(model.output)` it gives a Keras Tensor:

```
<KerasTensor: shape=(5,) dtype=int32 inferred_value=[None, 3, 128, 128, 128] (created by layer 'tf.compat.v1.shape_15')
```

How can I get the actual values `[None, 3, 128, 128, 128]`?
I tried `output_shape.get_shape()`, but that gives the Tensor shape `[5]`.

Code to reproduce error:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
from tensorflow_probability import distributions as tfd

tfd = tfp.distributions

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Input(10))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation="linear"))
model.add(
    tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(
        lambda t: tfd.Normal(
            loc=t[..., :1], scale=1e-3 + tf.math.softplus(0.1 * t[..., 1:])
        )
    )
)


model.output.shape
```

Comment: Try `model.layers[-1].output_shape`

Comment: It didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tf.shape` will return a KerasTensor which is not easy to get the output shape directly.

However you can do this:

```
tf.shape(model.output)
>> `<KerasTensor: shape=(2,) dtype=int32 inferred_value=[None, 1] (created by layer 'tf.compat.v1.shape_168')>`
```

You want to get `inferred_value`, so:

```
tf.shape(model.output)._inferred_value
>> [None, 1]
```

Basically you can access any layer's output shape with:

```
tf.shape(model.layers[idx].output)._inferred_value
```

where `idx` is the index of the desired layer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked. One more question please, I saw your pull request with regard to the `channel_first` issue is merged on GitHub TensorFlow probability  (convolutional_variational.py). So when I import tensorflow_probability shouldn't it import that version instead? I still have to change the source code on Colab every time I run it.

Comment: I think that changing will be included in the new release unless you build TFP from source.

Comment: Can you please have a look at this question when you get a chance? It is related to data_format (channel_first) in tensorflow probability: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69052849/tensorflow-probability-input-to-reshape-is-a-tensor-with-630784-values-but-the

Answer (score 0):

To get the output shape of all the layers you could do for instance:

```
out_shape_list=[] 
    for layer in model.layers:
            out_shape = layer.output_shape
            out_shape_list.append(out_shape)
```

You will get a list of output shapes, one for each layer