# Tensorflow probability: InvalidArgumentError: required broadcastable shapes

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

My data has channels_first format. When I use tensorflow probability layers I get the following error:

Here is an example where the input shape is `[1,28,28]` and the reproducible code: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/shifdz/118ba79678712a10d47e087a5dbd4f93) (please make sure you are running the code on GPU.)

```
InvalidArgumentError:  required broadcastable shapes
     [[node gradient_tape/lambda/model_3_mixture_same_family_4_MixtureSameFamily_MixtureSameFamily/log_prob/model_3_mixture_same_family_4_MixtureSameFamily_independent_normal_4_IndependentNormal_Independentmodel_3_mixture_same_family_4_MixtureSameFamily_independent_normal_4_IndependentNormal_Normal/log_prob/model_3_mixture_same_family_4_MixtureSameFamily_independent_normal_4_IndependentNormal_Normal/log_prob/truediv/RealDiv_1 (defined at <ipython-input-22-243a182981d9>:9) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_7663]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node gradient_tape/lambda/model_3_mixture_same_family_4_MixtureSameFamily_MixtureSameFamily/log_prob/model_3_mixture_same_family_4_MixtureSameFamily_independent_normal_4_IndependentNormal_Independentmodel_3_mixture_same_family_4_MixtureSameFamily_independent_normal_4_IndependentNormal_Normal/log_prob/model_3_mixture_same_family_4_MixtureSameFamily_independent_normal_4_IndependentNormal_Normal/log_prob/truediv/RealDiv_1:
 model_3/mixture_same_family_4/MixtureSameFamily/independent_normal_4/IndependentNormal/Softplus (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/layers/distribution_layer.py:988)

Function call stack:
train_function
```

I am not sure how to change the source code so that it works with channels first input shape. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: I'm getting this error when trying to reproduce your error: `InvalidArgumentError:  Conv2DCustomBackpropInputOp only supports NHWC.
  [[node gradient_tape/model_7/sequential_17/conv2d_53/Conv2D/Conv2DBackpropInput (defined at <ipython-input-10-cf6a820743f5>:98) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_30892]`

Comment: @AlexandreMahdhaoui please make sure you can access GPU. Conv2DCustomBackpropInputOp only supports NHWC on device type CPU.

Comment: I got `TypeError: x and y must have the same dtype, got tf.bool != tf.float32` when running the Gist. I am using GPU, is there a specific TF version for reproducing? It would be easier if you share a colab link that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @Frightera I updated the gist. Here is the link to Colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1aXbRK0Xtn11haHb3mn8k7OUbD7624uj8?usp=sharing     .There isn't a specific TF version. Mine is TF2.6.

Comment: @DushiFdz I will check this tomorrow, if it is something related to the source code I'll have a look into it.

Comment: @DushiFdz That's something about shapes, changing `.batch(28)` while processing the dataset should work. If it does not work try `.batch(28, drop_remainder = True)`

Comment: @Frightera can you please explain a little bit more. The data I work with has input shape (4,128,128,128) and the shape of the logit layer is (3,128,128,128). If I want to fit a mixture model on the logit layer with MixtureSameFamily in TFP, I don't really understand how the shape should be changed in the source code. Code in the question is the closest example I could think of to reproduce the error.

Comment: I think you don't need to change something in source code if you set your batch size as 128 when you're working with your data.

Comment: Where exactly should I change the batch size? You don't mean the batch size that we set when fitting the model, right? Batch size in my model is set to 1, because otherwise I get a memory error. For example, if it's a MixtureSameFamily Layer, then in the last layer we can write, `tfpl.MixtureSameFamily(num_components, tfpl.IndependentNormal(event_shape))`. Where should I set batch size?

Comment: Ah yes I meant when fitting the model. Then if you use batch size as 1, I am not sure how you can get around this because some reshaping is performed in normal 2D Conv layers and that might not be compatible with TFP-Layers. I looked for possible errors in TFP source code but could not find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `preprocess` function is returning `image, image` instead of `image, sample['label']`. If you change this, it should work!

I think you can then drop the K.cast in your loss as well.

Update: actually when i run this i get nan's in the loss. Probably something else is wrong. But at least it gets past the shape error! ‍♂️

Comment: Thanks Chris. The data I am working with has shape (4,128,128,128) and the penultimate layer is  (3,128,128,128). If I do, ```params_size = tfpl.MixtureSameFamily.params_size(num_components,
     component_params_size=tfpl.IndependentNormal.params_size(event_shape))

    output_l = Conv3D(params_size, (1,1,1), padding="same",data_format="channels_first")(output_layer)
    output=tfpl.MixtureSameFamily(num_components, tfpl.IndependentNormal(event_shape))(output_l)``` I get the error: Input to reshape is a tensor with 18432000 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 442368

Comment: Hmm can you share another gist or (preferably if possible) a colab that reproduces this? Happy to take a look at that and try to help.